# bloodhound install fails due to virtual env

Tags: apache, apache-bloodhound

My bloodhound installation process fails due to virtual-env
I installed everything as listed [on their page](https://issues.apache.org/bloodhound/wiki/BloodhoundInstall) but when I run

```
virtualenv --system-site-packages bloodhound
```

I get

```
virtualenv: error: no such option: --system-site-packages
```

The virtual-env version on the system is `1.4.9` - is it too old?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it was added in [1.7](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv). I believe the default prior to 1.7 was to include global site packages, so I would recommend just omitting the option.